# Why array has been lost last item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const TestForm = props => {
  const [emailInput, setEmailInput] = useState([]);
  
  const removeEmail = useCallback( (e, id) => {
      console.log(emailInput);
  });
  
  const addEmail = () => {
      const timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();

      setEmailInput([...emailInput, <EmailInvitation
          key={timestamp}
          removeEmail={(e) => removeEmail(e, timestamp)} />] );
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input
            name="email[]"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Enter Email"
        />
      </div>
    
      {emailInput ? emailInput.map( eI => eI) : null}

      <button type="button" onClick={addEmail} />
    </div>
  );
}

const EmailInvitation = props => {
    const { removeEmail } = props;

    return (
        <div>
          <input
            name="email[]"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Enter Email"
          />
          <button type="button" onClick={removeEmail}>
            Remove
          </button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

When I click the button that has removeEmail function, I get `console.log(emailInput);` but this array lost last item.

Example: I have 3 inputs after click `addEmail` twice. When I click the first remove button, I got anything. Click the second remove button, I got only the first item in array, miss current item. Click the third remove button, it shows only 2 items (first and second)

This code on codesandbox.io : https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-oskar-jqbxz

Comment: The snippet doesn't quite run.  Can you fix it up?

Comment: @Wyck I fixed it, and https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-monad-efzxm

Comment: Both still appear broken to me.  Clicking the *Run code snippet* button results in: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"`. And the codesandbox.io results in: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't quite dug deep enough to see where/why, but my hunch that somehow the state was getting memoized into the callback seems confirmed. When I instead update your sandbox to store just the timestamps and state and render the `EmailInvitation` fully in the render cycle it appears to function as I think you intended/expected.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const TestForm = props => {
  const [timesStamps, setTimestamps] = useState([]);

  const removeEmail = (e, id) => {
    console.log(timesStamps, id); // full timestamps array and timestamp/id invoking callback
  };

  const addEmail = () => {
    const timestamp = new Date().getTime();

    setTimestamps([...timesStamps, timestamp]);
  };

  useEffect(() => console.log("timesStamps", timesStamps), [timesStamps]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input name="email[]" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" />
      </div>

      {timesStamps.map(timestamp => (
        <EmailInvitation
          key={timestamp}
          timestamp={timestamp}
          removeEmail={removeEmail} // link callback ref here
        />
      ))}

      <button type="button" onClick={addEmail}>
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const EmailInvitation = ({ timestamp, removeEmail }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input name="email[]" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" />
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={e => removeEmail(e, timestamp)} // invoke with event
      >
        Remove
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<TestForm />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit headless-butterfly-k3100]